# TAO 1.6a - How to make .a libraries?

Tags: static-libraries, aix, corba, ace, tao

I built TAO 1.6a downloaded from OCI in AIX 5.3. I was built successfully. However, I could only see .so files in $ACE_ROOT/lib. How to build it to get .a files? I have built 1.5a version and it gave me .a files. Is there any make flag? Please give ma sample.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TAO1.5 and older versions produce .a (archive library file) for each library.
For example: `libTAO.a, libTAO_CosNaming.a, libTAO_PortableServer.a, libTAO_AnyTypeCode.a`

I think why all libraries are put inside archive files is that the library names are the same as default, `"shr.o"`.

The fact is all library names are the same but only the archive names are different.

For example:

```
Archive Name            Library Name
------------            ------------
libTAO.a                  shr.o
libTAO_CosNaming.a        shr.o
libTAO_PortableServer.a   shr.o
libTAO_AnyTypeCode.a      shr.o
```

But, TAO1.6 and newer versions produces libraries with different names.
For example: `libTAO.so, libTAO_CosNaming.so, libTAO_PortableServer.so, libTAO_AnyTypeCode.so`

And, those libraries are not put inside archive files (.a). That is why I cannot find ".a" files inside `$ACE_ROOT/lib`.

If you want to create .a files for all libraries, please do the following steps.
I don't know if there are more easier ways out there. If so, please share here.

In `$ACE_ROOT/lib`, all .so files are symbolic linked from their original project directories.

So, find out from where. I will do `libACE.so` as example.

```
$cd ACE_ROOT/lib
$ls -lrt libACE.so
--> libACE.so -> ../ace/libACE.so.5.6a_p13
```

ok, now, I know the source of the file and will go there.

```
$cd ../ace
```

create .a file and put the source inside it.
usage - "ar -rv archivelibname.a sourcelibname"

```
$ar -rv libACE.a libACE.so.5.6a_p13
```

and go back to $ACE_ROOT and symbolic link the .a file

```
$cd $ACE_ROOT/lib
$ln -sf ../ace/libACE.a libACE.a
```

That's all. But, you have to do those steps for all libraries and it is tiring.

**Edit: I just did not know -brtl**

Compile projects using -brtl parameter and  they will work well with .so libraries.

Comment: The 1.6a version is pretty old, use TAO 2.1.3 and the tao-users mailing list is a much better place to ask than here on stackoverflow

Comment: On AIX theres no difference from .so and .a.  Just convention.  http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp7a.doc%2Fgetstart%2Foverview%2Fport_aix_obj_lib.htm

Comment: @CoreyStup Ah, sorry, I totally didn't read the AIX part of the question.

Comment: @JohnnyWillemsen I downloaded from www.theaceorb.com. I downloaded patch 13 which was released on 06-Jan-2012. So, I think it is not very old.

Comment: The patch is not old, but the original version is old and a lot has been improved in the full open source versio of TAO. Get the 2.1.3 version from http://download.dre.vanderbilt.edu, that is really much more stable and tested

Comment: Interesting article - https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!search/TAO$20%2811095$7C1%29$20ERROR:$20ORBInitializer$20Registry$20unable$20to$20find$20the$20ORBInitializer$20Registry$20instance:$20Invalid$20argument/comp.soft-sys.ace/3DN072k0T58/xUowHcvwzOkJ